# Location listener is not respond.Is it depend on OS also? I have to restate the phone for this

Tags: android, locationlistener

//On Button click I am getting the latitude and longitude by using location listener. Some time it called location listener some times not.I have to restate the phone then it work properly.Please Provide the best solution.

```
        mbtnCheckin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mrleMainCheckIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mprogressBarCheckIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            String serviceName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(serviceName);

            mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Current Latitude = " + location.getLatitude());
                        Log.e(TAG, "Current Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());   
                        mStrLatitue=Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                        mStrLongitude=Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                        if((WebServiceClient.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()))){
                             new locationAsync().execute();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                }



                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled");

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged");
                }
            };
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
            } else {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
            }
        }
        });

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);` from this part of code:

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener); //REMOVE THIS LINE
if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
} else {
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
}
```

Another thing you should do is disable button `mbtnCheckin` after it is clicked and wait for location acquired to enable it again. This prevents the button to be clicked again before the last location be handled